# How can I make functions follow a proper order?

Tags: c, gtk

I have this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#include "splash_screen.h"
#include "db.h"

/* Global declarations */
GtkWidget *splash_window, *splash_image, *vbox, *pbar;
int timer;

/* A timeout to make the progressbar be animated */
static gboolean progress_timeout (gpointer data)
{
    gtk_progress_bar_pulse (GTK_PROGRESS_BAR (data));

    /* Make this callback to be called again and again */
    return TRUE;
}

/* A function to destroy the splash screen */
static void destroy_splash_screen (GtkWidget *window, int timer)
{
    /* Finish the timer */
    gtk_timeout_remove (timer);
    timer = 0;

    /* Destroy the widget window and its children */
    gtk_widget_destroy (GTK_WIDGET (window));
}

/* Create the splash screen itself */
void splash_screen ()
{
    /* The screen */
    splash_window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    /* The properties */
    gtk_window_set_type_hint        (GTK_WINDOW (splash_window), GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_SPLASHSCREEN);
    gtk_window_set_decorated        (GTK_WINDOW (splash_window), FALSE);
    gtk_window_set_position         (GTK_WINDOW (splash_window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS);
    gtk_window_set_default_size     (GTK_WINDOW (splash_window), 300, 300);
    gtk_window_set_resizable        (GTK_WINDOW (splash_window), FALSE);
    gtk_window_set_title            (GTK_WINDOW (splash_window), "VadeTux [Cargando...]");
    gtk_container_set_border_width  (GTK_CONTAINER (splash_window), 0);

    /* The splash image */
    splash_image = gtk_image_new_from_file ("./imgs/splashscreen/end-splash.png");

    /* The vertical box */
    vbox = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 0);

    /* Create the progress bar and make it pulse */
    pbar = gtk_progress_bar_new ();
    gtk_progress_bar_pulse (GTK_PROGRESS_BAR (pbar));
    /* The timer in charge of the animation */
    timer = g_timeout_add (100, progress_timeout, pbar);

    /* Start the packing */
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (splash_window), vbox);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), splash_image, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), pbar, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    /* Show everything */
    gtk_widget_show_all (splash_window);

    get_page ("http://listadomedicamentos.aemps.gob.es/prescripcion.zip", "DB/prescripcion.zip");

    destroy_splash_screen (splash_window, timer);
}
```

EDIT: (most includes are for when I add an unzip function)

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <zip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "db.h"

void get_page (const char *url, const char *file_name)
{
    CURL *easyhandle = curl_easy_init ();
    curl_easy_setopt (easyhandle, CURLOPT_URL, url);

    FILE *file = fopen (file_name, "w");

    curl_easy_setopt (easyhandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, file);
    curl_easy_perform (easyhandle);

    curl_easy_cleanup (easyhandle);
    fclose (file);
}
```

The timer and destroy_splash_screen are statics that work good, and the get_page () is a CURL function. The problem is that, instead of following that order of (definitions; create window; paint window; do get_page; destroy window;) it will do (definitions; create window; do get_page; paint window; destroy window;).
This way, the screen is empty during the download, and the window is destroyed before you can see anything.

I've been looking around and haven't found anything about this, how can I fix it so it follows the order I want it to have?

Comment: Code runs in the order you provide it, but if you don't allow UI updates to occur (such as due to consuming the CPU in a blocking call that runs for a long time), you won't visually be able to confirm it. Caveat: this is a general UI code concept, I don't know gtk specifics.

Comment: Is your get_page function asynchronous? i.e. it does not wait for the function to complete before executing the next statement (destroying the window)

Comment: @Ervadac Exactly, it seems to start before the window is finished, and can't find a way to tell it to start afterwards, the window is created but can't paint before the get_page function starts. It doesn't wait. The destroy function works after the page_get, though.

Comment: You should post the code of the get_page function instead of the window creation. I suppose it somehow creates a thread or fork before starting the download, so you should be able to wait for the thread to end (pthread_join might help)

Comment: @Ervadac Will do in the edit.

Comment: Regarding the documentation, it seems `curl_easy_perform` is synchronous, so check what it returns. Maybe it just fails. Have you tried to add a sleep or a wait before destroying the splash screen?

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to use the Gtk+ main loop (via gtk_main()) in order to show anything.

Comment: @LubomírSedlář That'd be in the int main () function, not there.

Comment: @Ervadac The sleep called before, during or after the functions just turn out to make everything last longer, but in the same way. Will try checking if the curl_easy_perform is failing in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an almost minimal example of a Gtk+ program with a worker thread. The program displays a progress bar and prints numbers to input for 10 seconds. You could do something else when the worker is done. However, since GTK+ itself is not thread safe, you should not access the widgets from any thread other from the one running the main loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

gboolean stop_program(gpointer unused)
{
    /* Idle function run in the main thread. */
    gtk_main_loop();
    return FALSE;
}

gpointer worker_func(gpointer unused)
{
    /* This code runs in the worker thread. */
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        g_usleep(1000000);
    }

    g_idle_add(stop_program, NULL);
    gtk_main_quit();

    return NULL;
}

gboolean progress_cb(gpointer user_data)
{
    gtk_progress_bar_pulse(GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(user_data));
    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    g_signal_connect(window, "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    GtkWidget *box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 6);

    GtkWidget *progress = gtk_progress_bar_new();
    gtk_progress_bar_pulse(GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(progress));
    guint timer = g_timeout_add (100, progress_cb, progress);

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), progress, TRUE, TRUE, 6);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), box);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    /* Start the worker thread before starting the main loop. */
    GThread *thread = g_thread_new("worker thread", worker_func, NULL);

    gtk_main();

    /* Wait for the thread to finish. */
    g_thread_join(thread);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This has been the issue that most time took me and you fixed it simply and fast, flawlessly. A trillion ton of thanks.